# Open Photo Album (UIImagePickerController) from Present View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, presentviewcontroller

Currently i open Camera View controller as present view controller that screen also has a pick image from gallery option.

now how can i launch picker controller from already presented view controller or any other options are available to open photo album from present screen.

Comment: You need to change `UIImagePickerController`'s `sourceType` to `.photoLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

You can present UIImagePickerController from any view controller. Just check the sample,

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks Vicky but i have to launch image picker from viewcontroller that already is in  present mode.

Comment: @AnkitGupta, You can present a view controller from any view controller.